# SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier - Error installing shopify Cli on windows

Tags: node.js, shopify

I'm tryiong to install shopify Cli in windows with this command following the [documentation](https://shopify.dev/docs/themes/tools/cli/install)

```
npm i -g @shopify/cli@pre @shopify/theme@pre
```

But when I check the Cli version with

```
shopify version
```

I get this error message

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Nodist\bin\node_modules\@shopify\cli\bin\run.js:5
import runCLI from '../dist/index.js'
       ^^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
        at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:749:23)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:816:10)
        at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:672:32)
        at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:612:12)
        at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:604:3)
        at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:868:12)
        at internal/main/run_main_module.js:21:11
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: What is your Node version?

Comment: According to the documentation, you need `Node.js 14.17.0 or higher`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated node version and it worked!